# How to transpose pandas data frame by a column and value?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, series, transpose

I have a dataframe like this

**Input**

```
student_id  rep
abc100      1   
abc101      2
abc102      1
abc103      2
abc104      1
abc105      2
abc106      1
abc107      2
```

**Expected output**

```
1       2
abc100  abc101
abc102  abc103
abc104  abc105
abc106  abc107
```

I tried

```
df = df.pivot( columns='rep', values='student_id')
```

but it contains lot of nans and didnt give expected output.

I searched in stackoverflow but couldnt find an answer.

Comment: as a general advice please provide sample in text, not images

Comment: `df.reset_index().pivot('index','rep', 'student_id')`

Comment: @coldspeed that doesn't yield the desired output but maybe that's because of my index assumptios

Comment: @coldspeed your solution doesn't work and this is not a duplicate. I would suggest you reopen this question.

Comment: @Yuca Perhaps The index should be the result of groupby and cumcount... hmm, yeah that might work.

Comment: @GeorgeOfTheRF Gladly... just need to wait for OP to replace their images with text ;-)

Comment: @coldspeed that's effectively what I suggested. It's scary how some solutions match exactly how others think, makes me feel good hehe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match the exact desired output you could do

```
df['aux'] = df.groupby('rep').cumcount()
df.pivot(index='aux' ,columns='rep', values='student_id')
```

Output:

```
rep       1       2
aux                
0    abc100  abc101
1    abc102  abc103
2    abc104  abc105
3    abc106  abc107
```

Comment: Almost... I would've done `df.assign(index=df.groupby('rep').cumcount()).pivot('index', 'rep', 'student_id')` to avoid modifying the original, but this is effectively more efficient. +1

Comment: when people seem relatively new I prefer to provide the slow but readable solution. However, one liners are just too pretty and elegant

Answer (score 0):

You can choose df by slicing the column using iloc and a step arg:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({'student_id':df['student_id'].iloc[::2].values, 'student_id_1':df['student_id'].iloc[1::2].values})
  student_id student_id_1
0     abc100       abc101
1     abc102       abc103
2     abc104       abc105
3     abc106       abc107
```

OR , another way around as @coldspeed suggested just for the wide visibility :-)

```
df.assign(index=df.groupby('rep').cumcount()).pivot('index', 'rep', 'student_id')
```